# Why Does Session Abandon Not Work?

Tags: session, asp-classic, iis-6

I have following code

cx5_login.asp

```vb
Session("Login") = "demo"
```

cx5_logout.asp :

```vb
Session("Login") = ""
Session.Abandon
response.redirect "c5x_login.asp?C5xName=Login"
```

I want to know if `Session.Abandon` will remove `Session("Login")`?
Currenly, I am check for `Session("Login")` to determinate if the user is login or not.
But it doesn't work.

Scenario:

1. User login
2. User logout
3. I print value from `Session("Login")` and it's still have value.

I have called Session.Abandon but why `Session("Login")` still have value?
Is it related with `ASPSESSIONID` cookie?
I try to remove that cookie manually and it's work.

Any explanation for this?

Answer (score 5):

What [Neel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997103/neel) [say's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23404172/692942) isn't wrong but it isn't right either, the problem is and constantly tends to be either question askers or people answering confusing Classic ASP with ASP.Net.

If your question is Classic ASP related then when talking about the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524319(v=vs.90).aspx) object you need to consider the following.

`Session.Abandon()` should be used to completely dispose a session including the `Session.SessionID`.

*But there is a cavert;*

> Quote from the [MSDN Library - Session.Abandon()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310(v=vs.90).aspx)
>
> *"When the Abandon method is called, the current Session object is queued for deletion but is not actually deleted until all of the script commands on the current page have been processed. This means that you can access variables stored in the Session object on the same page as the call to the Abandon method but not in any subsequent Web pages."*

This means that within the context of the current page your Session is still available, it isn't until you move on to another page that the `Session` object is actually disposed.

If you don't redirect after your log out page your Session will still be accessible but rest assured that any attempt to access it after leaving that page will fail.

> As a test don't automatically redirect after logout but give the users a link to press and see if you get the same behaviour.

Comment: But I still got the session value after `Session.Abandon()` and redirect to another page. Why?

Comment: @IswantoSan What happens if you do a manual change to another page rather then doing a redirect, do you still see the session?

Comment: @IswantoSan Is the behaviour the same in all browsers?

Comment: Yes same, I am using mozilla and IE. I have tried to login, logout, close the browser, then directly type the home page (which is user must login first), I still can read the Session value. FYI, I am using IIS 6